# What happened to user user9413?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

I see answers by user9413 but no link to profile. What's the story with that?
foe example :
[Is there an integral that proves $\pi > 333/106$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1956/is-there-an-integral-that-proves-pi-333-106)

The user id is not a link.

Thanks

Comment: This typically means the account was deleted.

Comment: @mixedmath : By user? if not any reasons known?

Comment: Users cannot delete their own accounts. Instead, they must request that their accounts be deleted, and so on. But the reasons are lost with time.

Comment: It can also mean, in the case of BenjaLim, that some funky auto-merging happened. But this is not the case here, I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That means the account was deleted.